# Flask-Sqlalchemy saving children one-to-many issue

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am very confused and I am trying to add children to an existing parent object in the database. When trying to do that I get an error.

I am unsure about how to make sure my newly added children object gets saved?
The error and my attempts are below:

```
equityLinkedNote = db.session.query(EquityLinkedNote).filter(EquityLinkedNote.cmdb == cmdb_eln.cmdb)
underlier_list = underliers.to_dict(orient="records")
    equityLinkedNote.Underlier =\
                [UnderlierDetails(
                Ticker=underlier["Ticker"] if "Ticker" in underlier else None,
                Weight=underlier["Weight"] if "Weight" in underlier else None,
                ReturnFloor=underlier["ReturnFloor"] if "ReturnFloor" in underlier else None,
                InitialFixing=underlier["InitialFixing"] if "InitialFixing" in underlier else None,
                ReturnCap=underlier["ReturnCap"] if "ReturnCap" in underlier else None,
                EffectiveDate=underlier["EffectiveDate"] if "EffectiveDate" in underlier else cmdb_eln.trade_date
                ) for underlier in underlier_list]
    db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()
```

**ERROR**

```
File "....\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 747, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "...\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 229, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "...\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 711, in set
    state._modified_event(dict_, self, old)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_modified_event'
```

I have no idea why this is failing. any help will be appreciated!

Here are my models

```
class EquityLinkedNote(GenericSecMasterObject):
    Underlier = db.relationship("UnderlierDetails", backref='note', cascade="save-update, merge, delete", lazy='dynamic',
                                collection_class=list)
```

**Underlier**

```
class UnderlierDetails(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "underlier_details"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Ticker = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    InitialFixing = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)  
    ReturnCap = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)  
    ReturnFloor = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)  
    Weight = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    EffectiveDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    cmdb = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('sec_master_details.cmdb'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here. You have not added anything to the session but you committing the session. Can you put more words into the post? It seems like you are querying some objects and want to update some fields

Comment: I added some more. Sorry its my first question on stack. thanks for your patience.

Comment: Still does not make sense. `equityLinkedNote` is a query object while `Underliner` is a dataframe. I am pretty sure query object is not related to a dataframe. You just need list of dicts which you can later pass to the session in order to update the objects.

Comment: i made it into a list of dicts using "underlier_list = underliers.to_dict(orient="records")"

Comment: Thanks for your help! @_mad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my error, for anyone who has similair issue, refrain from using the following in a db.Model, removed it and the error was resolved...

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    return None
```

Comment: yeah, that's the kind of thing that can bite you. Why was that in there?

Comment: i was defining a property using it

Comment: probably want to stick to @property for that- too easy to break stuff if you override the magic methods.